# .NET Web Service Security

Tags: c#, web-services, security

I have a C# web service on our website and I only want to be able to call it locally where its hosted - restricting access from the outside world. Whats the easiest way to do this without a login form? We cannot restrict the web service directory per ip (because I don't believe its static)

Comment: Chris, C# doesn't have web services. It's a programming language. .NET has web services.

Comment: Also, is this an old ASMX web service, or a WCF service?

Comment: ... because unfortunately we're only on .Net 2.0

Comment: Useless nitpick about C# / .NET. Is C# ever used without .NET? No. Therefore, C# implies .NET. The question isn't really at the code level, so whether it's C# or not doesn't really matter, but mentioning it doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also host them on a separate website, which you only bind to localhost (127.0.0.1)

PS: You should really get a static IP for your webserver. Or at least reserve an IP address for the server's mac address in your DHCP server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup windows authentication on the web services and require the authentication be a local account to that machine.  You'll have to modify your code calling it by providing network credentials, but that will prevent people from the outside calling it.

[This article should explain how to do it.](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020312.htm)

Comment: That link doesn't go to an article anymore.